# How can I disable the use of environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linux

I'm not using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my system currently, but there is one problem with it. One of my application is reading library files from one specific path as it was set. But when the application is running and if I place copy same library files to some different path for example '/home/sd' and set the environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to this path. Then the application starts reading the library files from '/home/sd'.  Which could be a problem if any intruder somehow been able to set this environment variable.
That's why I want to disable the impact of the environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is:

> How can I disable the use of environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Patch your dynamic loader implementation, so that it does not use the environment variable. In glibc, change [_dl_init_paths(getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/elf/dl-support.c#L328) to just `_dl_init_paths(NULL)`, recompile and install.

There's also running the binary in secure-execution mode. See `man ld.so` and `man getauxval`.

> Is there any way to do it?

Generally, except for recompilation, no.

If any intruder is able to set environment variables on your system, generally (`BASH_ENV`) you are domed anyway, and he will be able to execute anything anyway. Don't allow any intruders in the first place, and don't allow intruders to escalate permissions to set library paths.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I rebuilt and installed glibc with the change suggested by you and when I replaced the re-built libraries my device became unusable. I just changed the /lib64/ld.so file on my system with the rebuilt file, are there any other dependencies also?